# Compare columns in different Excel workbooks based on certain criteria

Tags: excel

Is there a way to compare 2 columns of data in 2 different workbooks based on matching certain criteria?

The sheets in question are horse racing results and so to make sure the selection is the same one, the date (A), time (C) and name (Q) need to match and the column I am wanting to compare is AR in both sheets.

The hope is to input the code into one sheet and have a TRUE or FALSE answer in the other, depending if the data matches or not. VBA is not the preferred way for this task, as the column for comparing will change as other columns are to be compared.

The sheet which will NOT have the code shows as this location when open [August2021.csv]August2021! I am using Excel 16 for Mac if that makes any difference

Here is an example of the original sheet with A, C & Q showing date, time and name (I have hidden the columns in between)

[image]

Here is an example of the sheet I am wanting to compare. The same columns A, C & Q, but with some differences in the 4th column. If the date, time and name match on both sheets, then it is the correct selection. I am then wanting to know if the 4th columns (AR) also match. The location of the file to compare is listed above.

[image]

With this second image, you can see there are some differences in the column labelled PR (the column is AR). The aim is merely to show differences where they occur, so whatever code is required will go into a cell in the original sheet and either a TRUE OR false will show

Thanks so much in advance.

I am trying to clarify things further, as once it starts to head to helper columns, it is all getting a little cumbersome.

Here is a code I have which matches columns A, B & C and then brings in the contents of column D from the second workbook.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/New Role/
[August.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$2:$D$50000,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2='/Users/SOS/Documents/
My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/New Role/[August.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$50000)*
(B2='/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/Horse/Football Advisor/New Role/
[August.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$50000)*(C2='/Users/SOS/Documents/My Documents/
Horse/Football Advisor/New Role/[August.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$50000),0,1),0)),"No")
```

This code works flawlessly matching those 3 columns and inserting the contents of column D.
Is there no way to tweak this code to have it COMPARE the contents of column D rather than inserting them? Column D is not the column I am after, but for the purposes of the exercise, is it possible at all?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO. Please, try to show some effort and searching. Also, data examples and expected outputs are useful.

Comment: Effort was made and there were NO example with exactly what I needed. I therefore posted this question. I'm not in the habit of asking a question for which an answer already exists. I have now added two images which hopefully clarify what it is I am after

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TEXTJOIN` to join array across multiple sheets, and `FIND` to search within the joined text which will return `#VALUE!` if not found. In my example the data is in H4:I8 across sheet1 to sheet3

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("text1, text2", TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,Sheet1:Sheet3!H4:I8))),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Note that this will also find occurences across rows and sheets, depending on how your data is set up this may not be a problem.

Comment: Cheers and thanks for your reply Tom. I can't see this will work, as I am not trying to find any particular text. I am trying to see if the data in cell ARxx in one sheet is the same as data ARxx in the other sheet. That is why it must use A, C & Q to determine if the selection is the same in both sheets. If A, C & Q are the same, then they are the same selection and I need to know if AR in both sheets is as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper column with combined values from all four columns in question in one workbook (`Book1.xlsx` below):

[image]

Then `VLOOKUP` to compare the helper column with the second workbook (`Book2.xlsx` below):

[image]

So the in the above example the following formula placed in `Book2.xlsx` worked for me:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2&D2;[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;FALSE)=A2&B2&C2&D2;FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately the sheets I showed as an example had the rows in identical places, but in reality, this is NOT the case, so I am wondering how that comparison can work. It is why I indicated A, C & Q must match. If the date, time and name of the horse are identical, then it is confirmed as being the same horse in both sheets. Is there a way for the VLOOKUP to NOT specify a row, but rather indicate anywhere in the column for the comparison?

Comment: The rows does not need to be in the same places. We can see that in my example: last two rows in the example (horse9 and horse10) are not sorted in Book1 as they are in Book2, yet they have the TRUE/FALSE status assigned properly. It will analogically work in your example as well, even with the data sorted differently in two workbooks, because VLOOKUP will find the rows with the data anyway (as long as data A, C and Q combined matches with the data in the helper column).

Comment: I actually can't get it accepted as code, Drzemlik. When I input it as is, it just sits there as code...no error, nothing. If I make any changes to the code, the usual error, "There's a problem with this formula..." Not sure if it is a Mac issue or what. The helper column for me is in CS and is the same as your code, except using A, C, H & Q. Here is the code in full ```=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&C2&H2&Q2;[August2021.xlsx]August2021!$CS:CS;1;FALSE)=A2&C2&H2&Q2;FALSE)``` Just an error message so far

Comment: I have added to the original post in the hope it will assist

Comment: What should assist in the original post? I see different formula there. Can you provide the exact error? Have you evaluated the formula in seach of exact problem with it?

Comment: I cannot add a comment to original post yet, so I am doing it here: helper columns, as any other columns with formulas, may be less cumbersome if one copy-pastes them as values. Excel won't calculate each cell then.

Comment: I have tried to recreate what you show, but it is simply not doing anything other than sitting there as code. I saved a copy of the workbook as Book1.xlsx and Sheet1. I added a column to the left of A and input ```=B2&C2&D2&E2``` in A2 and copied it to the bottom of the column as values. In the other sheet I input your code as is ```=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2&D2;[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A;1;FALSE)=A2&B2&C2&D2;FALSE)```. It simply sits there as code and does nothing. If I attempt to change anything in the code, a "there's a problem with this formula" appears. I am at a loss as to what else to do